Woocommerce integration issue
Hope you are doing well.
I recently installed ERPNext version 15 and tried to integrate with Woocommerce
Installed Woocommerce Connector
After Installing WooCommerceConnector and restarted ERPNext.
After following Documentation woocommerce_integration Documentation
 woocommerce_integration Documentation
I don’t see any updates on my ERPNext Dashboard under Home > Integrations > Settings > WooCommerce Settings. Can anyone help me solve this issue? I’m eagerly awaiting your response. Thanks in advance!"
Can anyone help me solve this issue?

I have run into the same issue. From the docks the integration is deprecated in version 15
https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/user/manual/en/woocommerce_integration
On the Frappe Cloud website you will see that the supported version is 13
https://frappecloud.com/marketplace/apps/woocommerceconnector
Visiting the GitHub repo for the integration, it was updated last ~1 year ago
https://github.com/libracore/WooCommerceConnector
In my opinion it just won't work on the newest version, but do let me know if you manage to get it working.

you will find it under something called WooCommerce Config
you can use awesomebar to search for it

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
